# Merge two lists side by side

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to duplicate some data scraped using beautifulSoup into two lists, replace the character "-" on one list, and then join the two lists side by side.

The original data (link) looks like so:

```
['example-of-link1','example-of-link2','example-of-link3','example-of-link4','example-of-link5']
```

The desired output

```
example-of-link1 Example Of Link 1
example-of-link2 Example Of Link 2
example-of-link3 Example Of Link 3
example-of-link4 Example Of Link 4
example-of-link5 Example Of Link 5
```

My code:

```
link4 = "\n".join(link)
link5 = link4.replace('-', ' ')
link5 = link5.title()


link6 = "\n".join("{} {}".format(x, y) for x, y in zip(link4, link5))

print(link6)
```

However this is the current output:

```
eE
xx
aa
mm
pp
ll
ee
-
oO
ff
-
lL
ii
nn
kk
11
```

Comment: Is the last digit 1,2,3,4.. is a single digit? Otherwise, we need some mechanism to extract the digit

Comment: @Epsi95 yes it's a single digit. I used this just as an example, "link" doesn't actually contain a digit at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
items = [
    'example-of-link1', 'example-of-link2', 'example-of-link3',
    'example-of-link4', 'example-of-link5',
]

print(
    "\n".join(
        f"{item} {' '.join(item.split('-')).title()[:-1]} {idx}"
        for idx, item in enumerate(items, start=1)
    )
)
```

Output:

```
example-of-link1 Example Of Link 1
example-of-link2 Example Of Link 2
example-of-link3 Example Of Link 3
example-of-link4 Example Of Link 4
example-of-link5 Example Of Link 5
```

EDIT:
As per your comment, try this:

```
print(
    "\n".join(
        f"<www.foo.com/{item}|{' '.join(item.split('-')).title()[:-1]} {idx}>"
        for idx, item in enumerate(items, start=1)
    )
)
```

Output:

```
<www.foo.com/example-of-link1|Example Of Link 1>
<www.foo.com/example-of-link2|Example Of Link 2>
<www.foo.com/example-of-link3|Example Of Link 3>
<www.foo.com/example-of-link4|Example Of Link 4>
<www.foo.com/example-of-link5|Example Of Link 5>
```

Comment: Perfect, and how would I get the following output:

```
<www.foo.com/example-of-link1|Example Of Link 1>
<www.foo.com/example-of-link2|Example Of Link 2>
etc
```

Comment: Thank you. The number system was just an example, should I just remove {idx} to remove it?

Comment: Sure, adjust the answer as much as you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mix of `regex` and `split()` with list comprehension as:

```
links = ['example-of-link1','example-of-link2','example-of-link3','example-of-link4','example-of-link5']
result = []
import re
for link in links:
    lst = [elt.title() for elt in link.split('-')] # extract the list elements by splitting
    str_digit = ' '.join(re.split(r'(\d+)', lst[-1])) #use regex to extract digits and string
    str_obj = ' '.join(lst[:-1]) + ' ' + str_digit # prepare the right part of string
    result.append(f"{link} {str_obj}") # merge the original element and new string
    
for elt in result:
    print(elt)
```

Output:

```
example-of-link1 Example Of Link 1 
example-of-link2 Example Of Link 2 
example-of-link3 Example Of Link 3 
example-of-link4 Example Of Link 4 
example-of-link5 Example Of Link 5
```

---

If the links don't have a numbers at the end then it is just splitting and joining as:

```
result = []
for link in links:
    str_obj = ' '.join([elt.title() for elt in link.split('-')]) # extract the list elements by splitting
    result.append(f"{link} {str_obj}") # merge the original element and new string
    
for elt in result:
    print(elt)
```

Output:

```
example-of-link1 Example Of Link1
example-of-link2 Example Of Link2
example-of-link3 Example Of Link3
example-of-link4 Example Of Link4
example-of-link5 Example Of Link5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myList = ['example-of-link1','example-of-link2','example-of-link3','example-of-link4','example-of-link5']

def myFunc():
    for item in myList:
        charList = list(item.title().replace("-", " "))
        charList.insert(len(charList) - 1, " ")
        for char in charList:
            out_string = "".join(charList)
        print(item +" "+ out_string)

myFunc()
```

Output:

```
example-of-link1 Example Of Link 1
example-of-link2 Example Of Link 2
example-of-link3 Example Of Link 3
example-of-link4 Example Of Link 4
example-of-link5 Example Of Link 5
```